# Como lidar com um processo cometa?

Tags: linux, c, segurança, unix

Analizando a API do linux notei que uma estrutura interessante é possível:

```c
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    while (1)
    {
        if (fork()) exit(0); // Altera meu pid
        setpgid(0, 0); // Cria um novo grupo de processos, o atual sendo o único membro

        // Agora executar alguma operação "maligna":
        usleep(1000);
    }
}
```

O que acontece aqui é que a cada iteração o processo vai criar um clone filho e se matar em seguida. Para todos os efeitos, isso é o equivalente a trocar o seu próprio ID. Depois uso o [`setpgid`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/setpgid.2.html) para abrir um novo grupo de processos incluindo apenas o processo atual, sem o processo original antes do clone. Assim a cada iteração o ID do grupo também é trocado. Depois executo uma curta operação e troco meus IDs denovo.

Esse tipo de processo é conhecido como **processo cometa** pelos administradores de sistemas.

O problema é que é muito difícil matar um processo assim, pois o [`kill`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/kill.2.html) precisa de um ID de processo ou o ID de um grupo e o tempo que eu levar para identificar o ID dele e enviar um kill, será tempo suficiente para que ele mude.

- **Por que esse processo não aparece listado?**
  Quando executo `ps -A | grep teste` (assumindo que meu executável se chama `teste`), por vezes o processo não aparece. Isso não faz sentido para mim. Entendo que eu alguns momentos existem 2 processo com o mesmo nome (o clone e o parente que ainda não se matou), e que na maioria do tempo exista um só. Mas zero não faz sentido. Ele não está em nenhum momento morto. Se eu repetir o comando um número considerável de vezes o processo é listado em algumas. Por que?
- **Como matar esse processo?**
  Ainda que eu consiga listar e obter o ID dele (após muitas tentativas) o tempo que gasto para chamar `kill` é suficiente para que ele se clone e se suicide. Posso tentar com o `killall teste`, mas o comando falha em quase todas as chamadas. Como efetivamente matar ele?
- **O fato de essa estrutura ser possível representa uma falha no design da API?**
  O que vejo aqui é uma API que permite que o ID do processo flutua e ao mesmo tempo dependa dele sendo estável como unica forma de matar um processo. Não seria isso uma falha no design original? Poderia ser considerado uma falha de segurança até?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use o sinal `SIGSTOP`.

O manual dos sinais está disponível (em inglês) no:

```
man 7 signals
```

Envio o sinal `SIGSTOP` para todos os processos com aquele mesmo nome usando o comando

```
killall -SIGSTOP cmd
```

em seguida, mate os processos:

```
killall -SIGKILL cmd
```

No entanto, é possível que o `killall` não consiga enviar o sinal a tempo, de forma que se estabelecerá uma espécie de race condition.

Sendo assim, é preciso diminuir o limite de processos que aquele usuário pode criar, através do `ulimit -u`, assim, o kernel o impedirá de fazer `fork()`.

No entanto, uma vez atingido, esse limite também impedirá que você utilize o `killall`.

Uma das maneiras de contornar isso é, antes de baixar o limite, criar um outro usuário com `uid` igual a 0, e utilizar esse usuário para matar o processo.

Comment: Infelizmente o `killall` falha afirmando que o processo não existe (provavelmente mudou de ID logo depois de ele resolver o nome e antes de ele enviar o sinal). No entanto se eu repetir esse comando alguns milhões de vezes em sequencia, um terá sucesso e matará meu processo. É essa a única alternativa?

Comment: Discussão bem interessante, no mínimo, curiosa! Tá, e se o nome do binário desse cometa for _init_ , qual a solução?

Comment: O root não consegue matar o `init` no linux, @cemdorst

Comment: Acho que consegue sim.

  #pkill init 

não funciona?

Answer (score 5):

Com certeza o cara que disparou esse processo é do mau, então, sem piedade para ele:

```
# su - <maligno>
$ kill -9 -1
```

Caso não saiba o usuário , ou tenha receio de fazer isso, analise os usuários que estão conectados na máquina primeiro

```
# w
 09:22:33 up 24 days, 22:01,  5 users,  load average: 0.18, 0.18, 0.17
USER     TTY      FROM              LOGIN@   IDLE   JCPU   PCPU WHAT
usuario  :0       -                01Sep14 ?xdm?   8:56m  0.10s /bin/sh /usr/bin/startkde
usuario  pts/1    :0               01Sep14 24days  0.00s  4:10  kded --new-startup
usuario  pts/3    :0               08:46    0.00s  0.15s  0.08s /bin/bash
usuario  pts/5    :0               08:55    1:08   0.26s  0.13s /bin/bash
maligno  pts/8    cometa           09:21    1:08   0.08s  0.08s -sh
```

considere a hora de login, consumo de CPU e método de conexão na analise. Feito isso, você terá critérios para mandar o processo cometa de volta para o espaço!

Answer (score 1):

Acho que usar o `killall` seria a única solução que não envolve mexer no kernel do sistema. Mas como você mesmo disse ele pode se enrolar já que a constante criação e eliminação de processos pode acontecer de forma assíncrona e em paralelo.

Porém essa condição não vai acontecer em 100% das vezes, eventualmente ele vai conseguir pegar esse cometa pelo rabo, basta ficar repetindo a ação até ela ser bem sucedida.

O artifício que você pode usar pra aumentar suas chances é o `nice`, que aumentará a prioridade de execução do `killall` fazendo que ele tenha uma janela de ação maior que a do programa alvo.

```
nice -n -20 killall -9 nome_do_processo
```

Answer (score 0):

O ID do grupo do processo (PGID) não muda quando ele faz o fork. Você pode matar (ou mandar um SIGSTOP) enviando um sinal pro grupo do processo -- faça `kill` + mais o PGID ao invés do PID.

Comment: Mas eu mudei o ID do grupo com o `setpgid(0, 0);`.

Comment: Porque vocês tão traduzindo perguntas e resposta do site em inglês? Só pela reputação?

Comment: @motobói Essa não é uma tradução. É uma dúvida real minha que tenho a bastante tempo.

Comment: @motobói Traduzir perguntas do SO em inglês não é proibido. Vide http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/a/19/2488

Comment: Bom, se a dúvida é pra valer, então o que você pode fazer nesse caso é usar o sinal STOP, que vai impedir o processo de fazer fork. Depois que todos os filhos receberem o sinal, você pode matar eles normalmente. `killall -SIGSTOP cmd; killall -SIGKILL cmd`