# Como exibir o PGID dos processos em execução?

Tags: linux, processo

No Linux, gostaria de saber qual comando uso para exibir o **PGID** dos processos em execução.

Vi em uma resposta aqui no SOePT que poderíamos matar um processo (comando kill) usando o PGID do processo. Mas usando o comando `ps` vejo apenas o PID.

Comment: Também é possível matar o processo usando o `PID`. Por que, especificamente, usar o `PGID`? É para matar todos os processos de um grupo de usuários?

Comment: Minha dúvida começou a partir daqui: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/3522/como-lidar-com-um-processo-cometa/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Você pode utilizar o `ps` mesmo, passando a opção `j`. No exemplo abaixo o `-e` é utilizado para mostrar todos os processos.

```
ps -ej
```

Se quiser saber mais, consulte o `man` do `ps`:

```
man ps
```

Answer (score 2):

Vou mostrar apenas mais uma maneira de fazer que eu encontrei. É bem flexível:

Usando o comando `ps` mesmo. Mas passando opções ao comando. Essa é a assinatura da chamada:

```
ps o <campos a ser exibido>
```

Exemplos:

**Chamada simples:**

```
[root@alab ~]# ps
  PID TTY          TIME CMD
 1946 pts/0    00:00:00 bash
 1966 pts/0    00:00:00 ps
```

**Chamada com o PGID:**

```
[root@alab ~]# ps o pgid
 PGID
 1463
 1465
 1467
 1469
 1475
 1582
 1946
 1970
```

Perceba que quando passamos o `o` devemos informar exatamente quais colunas queremos exibir. Então para ficar algo mais completo e adicionarmos o PGID podemos usar o comando da seguinte maneira:

**Chamada mais completa:**

```
[root@alab ~]# ps axo pid,pgid,tty,time,comm
  PID  PGID TT           TIME COMMAND
    1     1 ?        00:00:00 init
    2     0 ?        00:00:00 kthreadd
    [...cut...]
 1463  1463 tty2     00:00:00 mingetty
 1465  1465 tty3     00:00:00 mingetty
 1467  1467 tty4     00:00:00 mingetty
 1469  1469 tty5     00:00:00 mingetty
 1473   470 ?        00:00:00 udevd
 1474   470 ?        00:00:00 udevd
 1475  1475 tty6     00:00:00 mingetty
 1493  1493 ?        00:00:00 auditd
 1516  1159 ?        00:00:00 console-kit-dae
 1582  1582 tty1     00:00:00 bash
 1894  1894 ?        00:00:00 dhclient
 1942  1942 ?        00:00:00 sshd
 1946  1946 pts/0    00:00:00 bash
 1975  1975 pts/0    00:00:00 ps
```